# negative float values in groovy not retained as they are

Tags: groovy

I have a value coming from database as -0.01, but I have defined the variable as float type 0f.

and it is converting it to "0" only.

Is it possible to define the value as it is (by changing from 0f to some other float format) ?

(The system which supports is groovy 1.5.6)

Comment: How are you loading the value from the database?  How is the float variable declared?  Please post code.

Comment: the variables are declared as def otherMargin = 0f. The retrieval from database is custRecord.DOM_OTHER_MARGIN where custRecord is defined as def custRecord

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented using big Decimal, looks ok now.